# How to calculate the following mathematical expression in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula

I am trying to calculate the total money that can be made from dollar cost averaging every year using Google Sheets. For example: how would I evaluate this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I remember my highschool days, your expression reads :

> Sum of the `n` from `1` to `30`.
>   I.E. `1000*1.07^1 + 1000*1.07^2 + 1000*1.07^3 + ...`

Here's a way to do it :

```
=sum(ArrayFormula(1000*power(1.07,(ROW(A1:A30)))))
```

Result is `101 073.04`